# Adding a variable to an input parameter that is a prompt

Tags: c++

I have this function that is to validate integer input. As you can see there are three input parameters. (A prompt, lowerlimit and upperlimit)

```
double getValidNumber( string prompt, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
{
    double num;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> num;


    while (num < lowerLimit) {
    cout << "Entry must be greater than or equal to " << lowerLimit << endl;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> num;
    }
    while (num > upperLimit)
    {
    cout << "Entry must be less than or equal to " << upperLimit << endl;
    cout << prompt;
    cin >> num;
    }

    return num;
}
```

one of the prompts needs to also have a variable (maxDays) in it and the rest is a string. This call is made from main

```
//calls function to validate year of pickup
year = getValidNumber
("Enter pick up year (2014-2024): ", 2014 , 2024);

//calls function to validate month of pickup
month = getValidNumber
("Enter pick up month (1-12):  ", 1 , 12);

//calls function to get max days in month
maxDays = daysInMonth (year, month);

// If a user inputs 2014, 2 (for Feb) there are only 28 days this year
// I need the prompt to be "Enter pick up day (1-28): 
//calls function to validate pickup day is within month
day = getValidNumber
("Enter pick up day (1- maxDays)", 1, maxDays);
```

Im not sure how I can get a variable into this prompt.

Comment: look at std::stringstream http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you modify that function of yours..

```
double getValidNumber( string prompt, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
{
    double num;
    while (true)
    {
         cout << prompt;
         cin >> num;
         if (num < lowerLimit)
         {
             cout << "Entry must be greater than or equal to " << lowerLimit << endl;
         }
         else if (num > upperLimit)
         {
             cout << "Entry must be less than or equal to " << lowerLimit << endl;
         }
         else
         {
             return num;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow I feel dumb about that break....that i couldn't figure out to put else return num

Comment: Once the program meets the requirement that it is between the two bounds, and since it has nothing else to do.. It will return the last input (which is the value between the bounds)

Answer (score 0):

(Since I can't format code in a comment) There are many ways to fix your solution. One such way is that you could write another function called `getValidNumberDay()` function that looks like this:

```
double getValidNumberDay( string prompt, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
{
    double num;
    bool choice = 0;
    while (choice == 0) {
        cout << prompt << upperLimit << ")";
        cin >> num;
        if (num < lowerLimit)
        {
            cout << "Entry must be greater than or equal to " << lowerLimit << endl;
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> num;
        }
        else if (num > upperLimit)
        {
            cout << "Entry must be less than or equal to " << upperLimit << endl;
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> num;
        }
        else
        {
            choice = 1;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Then, rewrite your function call with `maxDays` to look like so:

```
day = getValidNumberDay
("Enter pick up day (1- ", 1, maxDays);
```

That should fix the problem!